# SQL multiple phone numbers on multiple rows - how to move all fields into 1 row

Tags: mysql, row, case

I need to combine 3 phone numbers for a user into one row. The end result would look like this

**contactId | phone | mobile | fax**

my tables look like this with the phone numbers broken into their own rows by phoneTypeId

---

**contact_phone_link**
contactId | contactPhoneNumberId
3344 | 1

---

**contact_phone_numbers**
id | phoneTypeId | phoneNumber
123 | 1 | 555-555-5555

---

**phone_types**
id | phoneTypeName
1 | Phone
2 | Mobile
3 | Fax

---

Dana thanks for your help, I'm getting closer to understanding this. I see how it's grouping and naming and then grouping again.

I've gone through and adjusted the syntax, but I'm still having problems where it gets to 'phone_link.phoneTypeId'. I think it's because 'contact_phone_link' doesn't hold 'phoneTypeId'. Also it gets hung up when the SELECT section and JOIN section had the same variable name like 'phone' so I added a 1.

Tell me if I'm way off.

```
SELECT
    `ct`.`id` AS contact_id,
    `phone1`.`lineNumber` AS phone,
    `fax1`.`lineNumber` AS fax,
    `mobile1`.`lineNumber` AS mobile

FROM `cmd`.`contacts` AS ct

LEFT JOIN `cmd`.`contact_phone_link` AS `phone_link` ON (`phone_link`.`contactId` = `ct`.`id` AND `phone_link`.`phoneTypeId` = 1)
LEFT JOIN `cmd`.`contact_phone_numbers` AS `phone1` ON (`phone`.`id` = `phone_link`.`contactPhoneNumberId`)

LEFT JOIN `cmd`.`contact_phone_link` AS `fax_link` ON (`fax_link`.`contactId` = `ct`.`id` AND `fax_link`.`phoneTypeId` = 2)
LEFT JOIN `cmd`.`contact_phone_numbers` AS `fax1` ON (`fax`.`id` = `fax_link`.`contactPhoneNumberId`)

LEFT JOIN `cmd`.`contact_phone_link` AS `mobile_link` ON (`mobile_link`.`contactId` = `ct`.`id` AND `mobile_link`.`phoneTypeId` = 3)
LEFT JOIN `cmd`.`contact_phone_numbers` AS `mobile1` ON (`mobile`.`id` = `mobile_link`.`contactPhoneNumberId`)

WHERE (`ct`.`id` = 4160);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited solution below.

```
SELECT
    `ct`.`id` AS contact_id,
    `phone_sub_query`.`lineNumber` AS phone,
    `fax_sub_query`.`lineNumber` AS fax,
    `mobile_sub_query`.`lineNumber` AS mobile

FROM `cmd`.`contacts` AS ct

left join
    (select `phone_link`.`contactId`, `phone_number`.`lineNumber`
    from `cmd`.`contact_phone_link` AS `phone_link`
    join `cmd`.`contact_phone_numbers` AS `phone_number` ON (`phone_number`.`id` = `phone_link`.`contactPhoneNumberId`)
    where `phone_number`.`phoneTypeId` = 1) as `phone_sub_query` on `phone_sub_query`.`contactId` = `ct`.`id`

left join
    (select `phone_link`.`contactId`, `phone_number`.`lineNumber`
    from `cmd`.`contact_phone_link` AS `phone_link`
    join `cmd`.`contact_phone_numbers` AS `phone_number` ON (`phone_number`.`id` = `phone_link`.`contactPhoneNumberId`)
    where `phone_number`.`phoneTypeId` = 2) as `fax_sub_query` on `fax_sub_query`.`contactId` = `ct`.`id`

left join
    (select `phone_link`.`contactId`, `phone_number`.`lineNumber`
    from `cmd`.`contact_phone_link` AS `phone_link`
    join `cmd`.`contact_phone_numbers` AS `phone_number` ON (`phone_number`.`id` = `phone_link`.`contactPhoneNumberId`)
    where `phone_number`.`phoneTypeId` = 3) as `mobile_sub_query` on `mobile_sub_query`.`contactId` = `ct`.`id`

WHERE (`ct`.`id` = 4160);
```

Given your table structure, I think using sub-queries might be required.  My solution actually looks a little more like @Eugene's now, but you want to `left join` against an `inner join`. My sub-queries check the phone type and emit (a) a contact id and (b) a line number.

Let me know if this works.  I think it should be closer.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response and your assumptions are correct. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'm sure the left join approach is the answer I'm looking for, but it will take me a while to get the syntax correct. Is the top SELECT section at the top creating fake tables to place the joined information in?

Comment: Essentially I am using the `contact` table to define the rows in the results.  Each phone number requires 2 left joins, filtered by phone number type.  If you were to run a `select *` you would have contact_column_count + (3 * contact_phone_link_column_count) + (3 * contact_phone_link_column_count) columns.  I am just picking the applicable columns... Does this make sense?

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to understand the approach. Just to be clear, the top SELECT section are a type of variable tables that don't exist? I say that because I don't have anything equivalent to fax.`lineNumber` as `fax` because all my phone numbers are in a single table.

Comment: Also what is the ct part of FROM `cmd`.`contact` ct? are you renaming the contact table to now be called ct?

Comment: @Jameson - Renaming the tables is *exactly* what I am doing.  This is often referred to as creating an alias.  If you refer to the MySQL docs, you can see a table reference is defined as `tbl_name [[AS] alias]`.  I will modify my query to add the `as` in there, but it is not needed.  (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Dana I'm getting closer to understanding the concept. I made my changes above if you see where I'm going wrong. Thanks!!!

Comment: That worked! Thanks to you both. I'll study what you've done here and keep learning. Now that I have the format I can plug in everything else I have to tack on to this thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We need to create a table of `contactId`s and join the numbers to it:

```
SELECT
  idlist.contactId AS contactId,
  phones.phone AS phone,
  mobiles.mobile AS mobile,
  faxes.fax AS fax
FROM
  -- This builds the ID list
  (SELECT DISTINCT contactId
   FROM contact_phone_link
  ) AS idlist
LEFT JOIN
  -- This gets the landlines
  (SELECT
     contact_phone_link.contactId AS contactId,
     contact_phone_numbers.phoneNumber AS phone
   FROM contact_phone_link
     INNER JOIN contact_phone_numbers ON contact_phone_numbers.id=contact_phone_link.contactPhoneNumberId
   WHERE contact_phone_numbers.phoneTypeId=1
  ) AS phones ON phones.contactId=idlist.contactIs
LEFT JOIN
  -- This gets the mobiles
  (SELECT
     contact_phone_link.contactId AS contactId,
     contact_phone_numbers.phoneNumber AS mobile
   FROM contact_phone_link
     INNER JOIN contact_phone_numbers ON contact_phone_numbers.id=contact_phone_link.contactPhoneNumberId
   WHERE contact_phone_numbers.phoneTypeId=2
  ) AS mobiles ON mobiles.contactId=idlist.contactId
LEFT JOIN
  -- This gets the faxes
  (SELECT
     contact_phone_link.contactId AS contactId,
     contact_phone_numbers.phoneNumber AS fax
   FROM contact_phone_link
     INNER JOIN contact_phone_numbers ON contact_phone_numbers.id=contact_phone_link.contactPhoneNumberId
   WHERE contact_phone_numbers.phoneTypeId=3
  ) AS faxes ON faxes.contactId=idlist.contactId
```